# Passing JAAS config to bitnami/kafka helm chart for SASL/PLAIN

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, sasl

**Goal:**

I want to use bitnami/kafka helm chart with SASL enabled with the PLAIN mechanism for only the external client. (client-broker, broker-broker, broker-zookeeper connection can be in PLAINTEXT mechanism)

**What I have Done:**

I've set configured parameters in values.yaml file:

```
superUsers: User:adminuser
auth.externalClientProtocol: sasl
auth.sasl.jaas.clientUsers:
  - adminuser
  - otheruser
auth.sasl.jaas.clientPasswords:
  - adminuserpass
  - otheruserpass
auth.sasl.jaas.interBrokerUser: adminuser
```

And left other parameters as it is. But it doesn't seem to be enough. The broker container is going to backOff state when I try to install the chart.

**Question#1:** Aren't these configuration parameters enough for setting up what I'm trying to achieve? Won't these create a JAAS config file for me?

From Kafka documentation [Kafka_SASL](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl), I have to pass a JAAS config file for the broker. It can be done by `sasl.jaas.config` configuration parameter. For me it should be something like this:

```
listener.name.EXTERNAL.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
username="adminuser" \
password="adminuserpass" \
user_adminuser="adminuserpass" \
user_otheruser="otheruserpass";
```

But it doesn't seem there is any `sasl.jaas.config` available in bitnami/kafka.values.yaml.

**Question#2:** How can I pass this JAAS config file values if the answer for question#1 is **NO**? Should I use `config` or `extraEnvVars` for this?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Why is it going to backoff state? What is the error log?

Comment: And you should use `config` before `extraEnvVars`

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me:

```
...
authorizerClassName: "kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer"

auth:
  clientProtocol: sasl
  externalClientProtocol: sasl
  interBrokerProtocol: plaintext
  sasl:
    mechanisms: plain,scram-sha-256,scram-sha-512
    interBrokerMechanism: plain
    jaas:
      clientUsers:
        - yourusername
      clientPasswords:
        - yourpassword
....
```

I don't know why but I have to set `clientProtocol: sasl`
otherwise, I get `java.io.IOException: /opt/bitnami/kafka/conf/kafka_jaas.conf (No such file or directory)`
also, I didn't see the error till I set `image.debug: true`

Note: as u you probably see this will force authentication also between the clients inside the cluster

Comment: running into the same issue, any idea if it is possible to enable auth only for external clients?

Comment: Anyone got the solution? we also want to only enable auth for external clients only?